# как сделать так, чтобы введённое сообщение пользователем в телеграмм боте отправлялось в группу (чат) aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

как сдлеать так, чтобы введённое сообщение пользователем в телеграмм боте отправлялось в группу (чат) aiogram

Comment: алгоритм такой: 1. Получаете сообщение пользователя 2. Пересылаете его в группу

Answer (score 1):

в хендлере где получаете сообщение от пользователя вызвать функцию отправки сообщение, уже в другую группу, например,

```
await bot.send_message(GROUP_ID, message.text)
```

Comment: В GROUP_ID надо вставить айди группы, верно? Но у меня почему-то это не сработало. Надо импортировать ещё какой-нибудь модуль?

Comment: да, надо указать айди группы, так же этот бот должен быть в той группе куда хотите оправить сообщение